# Stop autopostback on keyboard input for dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, autopostback

Is there any way do delay the autopostback on a dropdownlist until the list actually loses focus?  I want to accept input from the keyboard without the page posting back after every keystroke.  For example, take this code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:ListItem >Test1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem >Tst1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem >twotest</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Say I want to select twotest.  I tab to the ddl and input 'tw' into my keyboard.  However, as soon as the 't' is entered, the page automatically posts back, while the 'w' input is lost.  Resetting focus doesn't really help any as then the ddl thinks that 'w' is the first input.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems impossible. You must remove AutoPostBack="true" and try another way to perform postback. Consider below solution:

when dropdown **ddlCountry** changed, the function **ddlCountry_changed** is called that trigger **btnLoad** click to perform postback. The button **btnLoad** is put inside an update panel so the page is not reload and you still have focus on the dropdown.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ddlCountry_changed() {
        document.getElementById('<%= btnLoad.ClientID %>').click();
    }
</script>

Country:
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" onchange="ddlCountry_changed();">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Vietnam" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="United State" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btnLoad" style="display: none" runat="server" OnClick="btnLoad_OnClick" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: I was hoping to stay way from more chunks of javascript, as the application is already a mess.  Updatepanels all around too, so I can't exactly use them as you have here.  OnBlur would probably work instead of onchange though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complicated than just handling the blur. You need to remove the onchange attribute (AutoPostBack="false") so keyboard navigation is possible and attach event handlers that submit the form when the value has changed via clicking, blur, or the enter key is pressed.

I ran into this same issue and created a plugin for handling this.  Check out https://github.com/bstruthers/AutoPostBack-Fix.